# Конечный автомат в telebot

Tags: python, flask, telegram, telebot

Как лучше всего реализовать конечный автомат для телеграм бота на базе telebot, написанный на Python? Нужно, чтобы пользователь мог перемещаться между категориями и разделами на всех уровнях. Писать функцию для каждого конечно же нереально. Есть база данных SQLite, но нет понимания как это лучше реализовать.

Comment: можно сделать матрицу переходов, или с помощью множества ифов менять состояния, в любом случае сначала автомат нужно графически изобразить, потом уже реализовать